# Caching issue in C# renaming the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-handling

I am facing a very strange issue of renaming images (please see screenshot)
when i click up/down buttons i rename both images to swap them. [image]

first two three times it works perfectly, but when i repeat this process it stops changing the images in the browser.

Further investigating i found that my code is working pefectly but the browse is caching the images that's why they dont change their position.

when i press cTRL + F5 i see changed images or if i move to any other page and come back to same page i again see right order of images, but on same page it does'nt happen :(

any one can put some light on it? how can i resolve this issue?

**Code of swapping:**

```
protected void rptImages_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"]);
            String path = Server.MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            if (e.CommandName == "Up")
            {

                SwapImagesOnUpClick(id, path);
            }

            if (e.CommandName == "Down")
            {

                SwapImagesOnDownClick(id, path);

            }
}

public void SwapImagesOnUpClick(int id, string path)
        {
               string oldFileName;
                string newFileName;
                string tempFileName;

                string basicPath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('\\'));
                oldFileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                tempFileName = "temp.jpg";


                //get new filename
                string[] fileParts = oldFileName.Split('.');
                newFileName = (Convert.ToInt32(fileParts[0]) - 1).ToString();

                string newFilePath = basicPath + "\\" + newFileName + ".jpg";
                string tempFilePath = basicPath + "\\" + tempFileName;

                // set already existing newfilename to temp
                File.Move(newFilePath, tempFilePath);
                File.Move(path, newFilePath);
                File.Move(tempFilePath, path);






         }
```

Comment: Is it posible for you to change the location of image1 to location image2 inside the generated page instead of renaming the files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if somebody have to face similar situation as mine just append: "**?timestamp**"
in image src in this way your image wont get cached and everything will work perfectly to achieve up and down image functionality using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you to change the location of image1 to location image2 inside the generated page instead of renaming the files